# How to iterate through list and pass each element as list containing itself as the only element?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am interacting with an API that requires a list containing only one element be passed as a parameter.

I am trying to perform the same operation for each element in a list of elements.

This is my simple example code:

```
category_ids = 13
temp = svc.call(session, 'catalog_category.assignedProducts', [category_ids])
```

This works well.

What I would like to do is to define `category_ids` to have several elements, such as `category_ids = [12, 13, 14, 15]` and perform the call to API where `[category_ids]` references each element in the list.

Is this possible?

Comment: IIUC, just write a loop? `for i in category_id_list: svc.call(stuff, [i] ) ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
temp = []

for category_id in category_ids:
    temp.append(svc.call(session, 'catalog_category.assignedProducts', [category_id])
```

After that you will have results of individual calls (for individual `category_id`s) in the `temp` list.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap this in a function (if I understand you correctly):

```
def my_call(category_ids):
    return [svc.call(session, 'catalog_category.assignedProducts', [category_id]) for category_id in category_ids]
```